# Objects in PHP theory

Tags: php, oop

This is not an exercise or something like this, i am studying PHP and i got confused with objects.

I need to execute the method **"pay"** in order to pay all the
 different persons; so, i need to complete the function **"salary".**
 The function receives an array object; all those objects "know" how to
 execute the method **"pay".** Also, i want to store the result in the
 array **"result".**

I did this but i dont know if this correct or not:

```
function salary($persons) {
  $results= [];

  $persons->pay();

  return $results;
}
```

Is this okay? I am a little confused about this

Comment: your logic seems OK - but all you're doing is using a `pay()` method and returning an empty array

Comment: Please try more yourself before asking a question, you can take a look to error log after testing your code.

Comment: What's the type of `$persons`?

Comment: @NicoHaase hey dude, how are you? persons is a char array

Comment: @treyBake , okay. How would you modify it?

Comment: @Student_new more or less how the answer below is :)

Comment: What do you mean by a "char array"? That's pretty unusual in PHP

Comment: @treyBake a guy below wrote this: "If the parameter is expected to be an array then it would be a good idea to type it as an array to avoid confusion". What does that mean?

Comment: @Student_new yeah and Dharman doth be right (providing you're on php7+) - it means to type hint the parameter as an array. It ensures anyone using the `salary()` function can only pass an array. Otherwise a fatal error is thrown - you can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: @NicoHaase what did you mean by "type". That array contains names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, param $persons is an array, so you can't do $persons->pay(), instead of that you must do a foreach:

```
/**
 * @param array $persons
 * @return array
 */
function salary($persons) {
  $results = [];
  foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $results[] = $person->pay();
  }

  return $results;
}
```

Comment: If the parameter is expected to be an array then it would be a good idea to type it as an array to avoid confusion.

Comment: I mean `function salary(array $persons) :array`